# How to insert an value into a NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I know that my question sounds stupid, but it doesn't work with my code:

```
#import "TermineViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface TermineViewController ()

@end

@implementation TermineViewController   {
    NSArray *tableData;
    int i;
    NSString *userid;
    NSString *selection;
    NSMutableArray *userids;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString: @"http://example.com"];
    NSString *dataString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    tableData = [dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@"--"];
    NSLog(userids);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return ([tableData count])/4;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView   {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cell.accessoryView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    //Declare all Labels
    UILabel *name = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    UILabel *service = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:200];
    UILabel *time = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:300];

    //Write into Labels and add one to int i (declared in implementation)
        name.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:i];
    i++;
        service.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:i];
    i++;
        time.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:i];
    i++;
        userid = [tableData objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *usrid = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", userid];
        [userids addObject:usrid];
    i++;

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    selection = userids[indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"User selected %@", selection);
    NSLog(userids[0]);
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"details"]) {
        DetailViewController *destViewController = (DetailViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        destViewController.userid = selection;
    }
}


@end
```

So, here are two issues: the first is that I don't get any values in my NSMutableArray (btw it is declared in the @implementation). The second is that I get following error message if the user scrolls in the TableView:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 20 beyond bounds [0 .. 19]'
>   *** First throw call stack: [...]

I don't know whats the matter? Yes, in my Array are 20 values, but the 20th exists!

Thank you very much!!!!

Greetings, Kitzng

Comment: Arrays in Objective-C are 0-based indexed, meaning that the first element is at index 0, and the 20th at index 19.

Comment: Check if `- tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is returning `[tableData count]`.

Comment: paste your function - tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:  code here. so we can check.

Comment: userid = [tableData objectAtIndex:i]: what are "userid", "tableData" and "i"?

Comment: *I don't get any values in my NSMutableArray* -- WHAT NSMutableArray??

Comment: This is a very poorly constructed question.  You do not provide pertinent listings.  You mention an NSMutableArray and there's no sign of one.  You do not provide exception traceback info.  And I suspect you don't understand the difference between declaring a variable and initializing it.

Comment: "btw it is declared in the @implementation". The whole point of your question is about a mutable array, but then you don't even show the declaration or where or how its being used. The most relevant part and your just casually mention it

Comment: @trojanfoe: it is my data array for the three labels

Comment: @achievelimitless: i is an integer, which is just counting (you know, the array includes 4 different values, so I need to count; it is just easier and it is not really significant)

Comment: @atanzola: userid is just for converting an integer into a string (declared in @implementation)

Comment: @all: I added the whole code in my question

Comment: If this is the whole code then where is tableData getting populated?

Comment: Created in @implementation; filled in viewDidLoad. Otherwise I don't know what you mean..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not creating the array anywhere, you have to do userids = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] before you can use it.

Comment: Thank you, but if I do that, I get following error: [__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8daaf70
2014-01-22 19:58:50.554 ControlAW[2509:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8daaf70'

Comment: Get that error when which line is executed? And where did you add the call to create the array?

Comment: I get the error when it prepares the view (so directly after launch) and I called it in the viewDidLoad-method. Is that wrong?

Comment: Did you mistype and do userid = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]  instead of userids = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init].

Comment: No, I typed userids (userids = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];)

Comment: It works!! :-) Thank you!! Well, do you know, why it breaks when I scroll, too? Would be great!

Comment: FYI NSLog(userids) will cause a crash in viewdidload

Comment: Yes, that's right. Do you know the other mistake?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in and debug it. See what value is being returned for numberOfRowsInSection, put a breakpoint in cellForRowAtIndexPath and see what happens when you scroll. You are probably telling the table there are more rows then there actually are or something like that, and when it tries to fetch the cell things go over bounds.

Comment: Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1 -> UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; It crashes directly after launching.

Comment: Here I get signal SIGABRT: name.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:i];

Comment: So check what i is at that point, check tableData is still a valid object. Check tableData has sufficient items for i to index it. Get more information about the crash http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: Well, another question: i is a normal int, but (how I saw it) I need to use a NSUInteger. But how to implement it in objectAtIndex? It does not work

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `i` is not defined. My guess is that you mean `indexPath.row` or `indexPath.section`. If there are no values in your array, the issue may be that you haven't initialized it when you start adding the objects, and then call something like

```
tableData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20]
```

but that's purely speculation based off of the details provided.

As far as the tableView scroll issue, if your array contains 20 objects, indexes [0...19] are the objects. If the table view, in `numberOfRowsInSection:` is returning something like `tableData.count + 1`, there will be not data at the index for the last row.